# Multiple boxplots in one in R

Tags: r, boxplot

Hi I need to plot a boxplot in R.
    I have two matrices a and b.
    I created a boxplot for `a` and want to create boxplot for `b` on the same plot for `a`.
    The boxplots of the `b` matrix should lie on the whiskers of the boxplot for `a`.

Is there a way I can do it in R ??

Answer (score 11, accepted):

To add a boxplot to an existing plot, just use the argument `add=TRUE`, viz:

```
##Some data
a = rnorm(20)
b = rnorm(20, 2, 0.3)

##The plots
boxplot(a)
boxplot(b, add=TRUE, col=2)
```

Comment: @csgillespie In your answer the two boxplots are stacked, is there any way to get a result like `boxplot(a,b)` with multiple calls to `boxplot`?

Comment: Why not use `boxplot(a, b)`?

Comment: @csgillespie because I have a variable numbers of boxplot and I do not know in advance that number.

Comment: `boxplot(NULL, b); boxplot(a);` Sort of works, but isn't great. Perhaps ask a question?

Comment: Does this apply to geom_boxplot, too?

Comment: you sir, have just allowed me to bypass ggplot2

Comment: Is there a way to control where on the x-axis the box plot is added?

Answer (score 0):

Solution is simple, need to *force* **ylim** *manually*, because plot is trimmed by values of variable 'a':

```
# Our data
a = rnorm(20)
b = rnorm(20, 2, 0.3)

# The plots
boxplot(a, ylim = c(min(a,b),max(a,b)), col = 1)
boxplot(b, width = 30, col = 2, add=TRUE)
```